# Ordenação com selection sort por tamanho e alfabeticamente

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou com um exercício da faculdade, mas preciso de uma ajuda. Preciso fazer programa que recebe uma lista contendo N `nomes` e retorna uma lista com todos os nomes recebidos ordenados pelo tamanho (quantidade de letras) o *selection sort*. Caso você tenha dois `nomes` de mesmo tamanho, a ordenação destes dois deverá ser alfabética crescente. Não posso utilizar a função `sort`.

Fiz a primeira parte de ordenar pelo tamanho da *string*:

```
def nome_ordena(nomes):
    for i in range(len(nomes)):
        i_menor = i
        for j in range(i+1, len(nomes)):
            if len(nomes[i_menor]) > len(nomes[j]):
                i_menor= j  
        nomes[i], nomes[i_menor] = nomes[i_menor], nomes[i]           
    return nomes
```

Tentei de várias formas ordenar alfabeticamente os que tem o mesmo tamanho, mas não estou conseguindo. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 4):

Basta incluir uma verificação a mais no `if`:

```
def nome_ordena(nomes):
    for i in range(len(nomes)):
        i_menor = i
        for j in range(i + 1, len(nomes)):
            # se tamanho é diferente, ou se o tamanho é igual, usa a ordem alfabética
            if ( len(nomes[i_menor]) > len(nomes[j]) ) or ( len(nomes[i_menor]) == len(nomes[j]) and nomes[i_menor] > nomes[j] ):
                i_menor = j
        nomes[i], nomes[i_menor] = nomes[i_menor], nomes[i]           
    return nomes

nomes = ['Agata', 'Bia', 'Ana', 'Carlos', 'Andrea']
print(nome_ordena(nomes)) # ['Ana', 'Bia', 'Agata', 'Andrea', 'Carlos']
```

Ou seja, eu vejo se o tamanho de um é maior que o outro, **ou** se os tamanhos são iguais e uma string é maior que outra. Isso funciona pois comparações entre strings com os operadores `>` e `<` [levam em conta a ordem lexicográfica](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types) dos caracteres.

Lembrando que há diferença entre maiúsculas e minúsculas, e também entre letras acentuadas:

```
nomes = ['Agata', 'Ágata', 'agata']
print(nome_ordena(nomes)) # ['Agata', 'agata', 'Ágata']
```